# Pyspark command moves to new line

Tags: pyspark

why is that the below query executed in pyspark moves to next line instead of executing the current command

spark 1.6 in cloudera VM 5.X

Created a rdd by name fprdd ( this command executed fine)

pair1rdd = fprdd.map(lambda x : (x[2] ,(x[0],x[1]))

Tried even selecting the command by Shift + Enter too  ( same in vain)

hitting enter takes to the new line

Can anyone help me with possible solution .

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the answer to this question, you should go thru what is [lazy evaluation](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/) in spark.

> All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute
>   their results right away. Instead, they just remember the
>   transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). The
>   transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to
>   be returned to the driver program. This design enables Spark to run
>   more efficiently. For example, we can realize that a dataset created
>   through map will be used in a reduce and return only the result of the
>   reduce to the driver, rather than the larger mapped dataset.